Optimizing objective with two variables multiplied with each other?
Let's say you want to optimize the following objective function:
$$\min_{a,b} \Vert a + ab + b - W \Vert_2^2$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n,p}$ are the learnable matrices, and $W \in \mathbb{R}^{m,p}$ is some constant matrix given to you.
Since $a$ and $b$ are intricately linked via multiplication, what are some ways to optimize these types of multi-variate objective functions?
Does plain gradient descent work? I don't think I understand it enough to say for sure.
After doing initial research, it seems like we can do greedy search: in each iteration, hold $a$ (or $b$) constant, then optimize on just a single variable $b$ (or $a$) via gradient descent. After each iteration, alternate the variable.
Greedy search sounds similar to coordinate descent, and I'm wondering if there are other methods that would be more robust overall and less prone to local minimas.
There seems to be another method called EM (expectation-maximization algorithm) which assumes either $a$ or $b$ is a latent variable, but aside from that, it feels like it is doing the same thing as greedy search, just in a stochastic setting.
What are other optimization algorithms out there that handle multiple variables that are intricately linked via multiplication other than greedy search?

FYI: this particular problem can be solved via a matrix decomposition called the "singular value decomposition" applied to W.

Thanks @JohnMadden I will read more into that. For this post I am more curious about the general strategy, so maybe I will edit the objective function such that it shouldn't be trivially solved without an optimization algorithm

As far as optimization algos go, folks consider this type of problem in the matrix factorization space; "nonnegative matrix factorization" or other nonlinear matrix factorization might be a good place to start, e.g. http://www.arxiv.org/pdf/2005.01317

Thank you! I will read that paper over this weekend. If I find an answer in these papers, I will post the solution myself here

Is it true that "plain gradient descent probably won't do well is these type of objective functions?" My intuition says yes, but I don't think I understand it enough to confirm or give a reasoning as to why

Plain gradient descent will work (e.g. find a local minimum). However, it's true that oftentimes we can do better by doing what you suggest, alternating between optimizing one and then the other, because there are commonly better techniques for solving these subproblems than gradient descent.
